# JAXB rename attribute

Tags: java, attributes, jaxb, rename

I have some class with a terrible long name, which is transformed into XML with JAXB. Using `@XmlRootElement(name="nicername")`, I am able to rename the outer XML tag to `<nicername>`.

How do I rename individual attributes with ugly names of the class to some nice name too ?

Comment: Thanks all, this question is answered. The trick is to use @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD).

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `@XmlAttribute` and `@XmlElement` annotations to change the XML names.  If you annotate the fields be sure to use the `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` annotation on the class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="nice-name")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class UglyName {

    @XmlElement(name="nice-element-name")
    private String uglyElementName;

    @XmlAttribute(name="nice-attribute-name")
    private String uglyAttributeName;

}
```

Or you can annotate the properties:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="nice-name")
public class UglyName {

    private String uglyElementName;
    private String uglyAttributeName;

    @XmlElement(name="nice-element-name")
    public String getUglyElementName() {
         return uglyElementName;
    }

    public void setUglyElementName(String name) {
         this.uglyElementNamne = name;
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="nice-attribute-name")
    public String getUglyAttributeName() {
         return uglyAttributeName;
    }

    public void setUglyAttributeName(String name) {
         this.uglyAttributeNamne = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your very valuable and instructive answer :-) It works !!  Great, great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can define alternate names for your object properties using:

- [`XMLAttribute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html) annotation for attributes
- [`XMLElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html) annotations for elements

Comment: I tried @XmlElement(name="better"), and it only will work if the name of the formal paramaters of the corresponding setter function is *not* equal to the private data member. Hmm. very weird. But..now I get two times the attribute, one time with the ugly name, and one time with the nicer name. What is up ??

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Method parameter names have no impact on the serialization process. You might want to expand your question with a code sample.

Comment: This is what works for me, that is it: 1) renamed the ugly object name, but: 2) also duplicated the result with the original name.

    @XmlRootElement(name="niceclass")
    public class UblyServiceObject extends GeneralServiceObject {

        public UglyServiceObject() {}
 
        @XmlElement(name="nicemember") private SomeList someList1; 

        public void setSomeList(SomeList someList2) {  
            this.someList1 = someList2; 
        }
 
        public SomeList getSomeList() {  
         return this.someList1;
        }
    }

Comment: Sorry for the bad lay-out, seems I do not have enough reputation to answer on my own question.

Comment: Your code looks ok, but you say it's duplicating fields in the generated XML?

Comment: @mercehandig - If you annotate the fields you need to specify `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on your class.  Otherwise you can annotate the get (or set) methods:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

Comment: The @XmlAccessorType annotation also fixed the need for unique formal parameter names, and the duplicate emit of data members. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

Both the @XmlAttribute and @XmlElement annotations can be remapped by name using identical syntax as the @XmlRootElement annotation. So, just attach the relevant annotations to each individual field/property you need remapped and provide an argument for "name".