# Rest facade to map xml to json

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, mapping

I'm confronted to a problem between two applications that we are using in my company. A CRM called Infonova and a mobile application.

The two applications have their own API, one is giving responses in xml format and the other one in Json.

The solution that I'm thinking to implement is to create an application that will be a facade API (gateway). This application will call the url API of the first application and will get xml response, and I'm thinking to map this solution to a json format and return it.

Since the attributes between xml and json are not the same, I want to know if there's a solution to map the two entities that will represent my responses.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: can you show your input XML and your output JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an XML [unmarshaller](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/oxm.html) with spring, call your service that returns xml, unmarshal response to that bean. And then you could return this bean in response from a controller annotated with `@Produces("application/json")`.

So, to sum it up. You have a controller that produces json, a bean containing field names you want in your json, and a custom unmarshaller for xml to populate those fields (custom because the field names between json and xml do not match).

Comment: Thanks!! That's exactly what i want to do, but do you have an example of a custom unmarshaller. Let's say that my bean is person with a String attribute called name, in the other hand we consume an xml that have a root element called <pers> with a sub-element called <nom> to define the name.

How can i map these two especially that the example that i found in the documentation need the bean during the unmarshalling process?

Comment: say for jaxb see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100680/jaxb-rename-attribute, you annotate your beans and provide xml names in annotations

Comment: Thank you sir!! :)